module doesn't show in VSCode auto import
this is my first module in typescript, because I usually only use pre-made modules.
The problem is that I don't get any simpledao in the list. And I can't find the correct url function when I type @url unless I import them manually like this.

But when I import manually like this, it is working perfectly, including the tests. It is just not showing at vscode auto-complete nor imports.

I've tried to modify package.json and included index.d.ts properly, but I think I missed something here.
index.d.ts
export declare function url(url: string): (constructor: Function) => void;
export declare function query(query: string): (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => PropertyDescriptor;
export declare function initialize(): Promise<void>;
export declare function remove(): (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => PropertyDescriptor;
export declare function insert(): (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => PropertyDescriptor;

package.json
{
  "name": "simpledao",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib",
    "test": "test"
  },
  "files": [
    "index.js"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "types": "./index.d.ts",
  "description": ""
}

It is also have been linked to node_modules directory

I don't know what else needed. Is there something I missed?
The code is typescript, and transpiled into ES. I've included "type":"module" in package.json
